# mod_rails make: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, passenger, mod-rails

I'm setting up mod_rails on a Debian server but somehow something got screwed up (it wasn't me :P ).

```
gem install passenger
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
sh: make: command not found

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fastthread-1.0.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fastthread-1.0.7/ext/fastthread/gem_make.out
```

gem is installed:

```
gem -v
1.3.5
```

ruby also fine:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i486-linux]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline5-dev
```

This should be everything you need to get passenger to build

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure you have make, gcc et al?

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Does "which make" point to anything?